# Multimedia object & memory consumption

Tags: android, multimedia

based on android documents, `Bitmaps` *usually* take so much memory(height*width*8).what about `Multimedia`? for example `.mp4` or `.swf`? how do they consume memory?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find the documentation about bitmaps requiring `height * width * 8` bytes? That implies 64 bits of information per pixel. I would expect at most 32 bits (4 bytes) per pixel, possibly 16 (2 bytes), depending on what the APIs allow.

As for multimedia formats, you most likely won't be processing SWF files on Android. If you're playing MP4 files, you won't be decoding them in software and memory should not be a concern.